# Characteristic polynomial above the complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the Characteristic polynomial of   $\begin{pmatrix}
    i+1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 3i-1 & 2-2i\\
    0 & 2-2i & 3i-1
\end{pmatrix}$

I know that there is not different in $det(xI-A)$ or $det(A-xI)$ is it different over the complex numbers?

$det(xI-A)=(x-i-1)*((x-3i+1)^2-(2-2i)^2)$

$det(A-xI)=(1+i-x)*((3i-1-x)^2-(2-2i)^2)$

Comment: Fortunately you got bunch of zeros. So show us what Char polynomial you get. We can help you to see if it is right.

Comment: @imranfat added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it holds $det(xI-A) = det(-(A-xI)) = (-1)^{dimV} det(A-xI)$, no matter whether the entries of $A$ are real or complex numbers. $(-1)^{dimV}$ can be omitted for determining the characteristic polynomial.

Therefore there is no difference over the complex numbers.

Comment: So in this case when $dimV=9$ there are the same

Comment: yes, the characteristic polynomials are the same